# Several query mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i will take some information from my database.

My Database: (log)

```
 ______________

| id | browser |
 ______________
```

Now I have about 20 log entries, and want to know the 3 most registered browser. The browsers are "Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE". The problem is, I do not like the Mysql query should look like. I've always just get a query to one browser out which looked like this.:

```
$firefox_query = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT COUNT(id) AS anzahl FROM log WHERE browser LIKE 'Firefox'");
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS count,
  browser
FROM
  log
GROUP BY
  browser
ORDER BY
  count DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do

```
select 
count(*) as tot,
browser
from log
group by browser
order by tot desc
limit 3
```

Comment: I also try your answer it works fine, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT browser,
       COUNT(*) AS browse
FROM tablename
GROUP BY browser
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b6c/1)

Answer (score 1):

you need something like:
select count(browser),browser from anzahl where browser in( 'FireFox','Safari','IE') group by browser order by 1 desc;

note that in your example like is misused. Like is to find a pattern, when your text is equal to something here 'FireFox' , then you use: WHERE browser ='Firefox'

Answer (score -1):

```
$most_registered = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT browser, COUNT(id) AS anzahl FROM log GROUP BY browser ORDER BY anzahl DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: No, I need the 3 most occurring browser from the table log.

Comment: Can you try my changes?